# how to add block of text

Tags: perl, sed

I am trying to add nagios service checks in similar looking huge text file.
I wanted to search for each host name (as pattern) and and append new service check block, after four lines. The script should be able to append new service check block after each occurrence of host_name.

```
                     OR
```

would like to search two patterns on two consecutive lines and insert below block of text between two searched patterns at every occurrence in text file.

P1 - notification_options    d,r
P2 - }

I know only basics of sed and any help will be really appreciated.

```
define service{
            use                     new
            host_name               new
            active_checks_enabled   0
            check_freshness         0
            service_description     new
            check_command           new
            check_period            24x7
}
```

---

```
define host{
    use                     linux
    host_name               lotus
    alias                   lotus
    address                 10.1.1.1
    notification_options    d,r
}
define service{
            use                     linux
            host_name               lotus
            active_checks_enabled   0
            check_freshness         0
            service_description     Host Alive
            check_command           check-host-alive
            check_period            24x7
}

define service{
            use                     linux
            host_name               lotus
            active_checks_enabled   0
            check_freshness         0
            service_description     CPU
            check_command           check_cpu!95!100
            check_period            24x7
            notification_options    w,c,r
}


define host{
    use                     linux
    host_name               palm
    alias                   palm
    address                 10.1.1.2
    notification_options    d,r
}
define service{
            use                     linux
            host_name               palm
            active_checks_enabled   0
            check_freshness         0
            service_description     Host Alive
            check_command           checki_host
            check_period            24x7
}

define service{
            use                     linux
            host_name               palm
            active_checks_enabled   0
            check_freshness         0
            service_description     CPU
            check_command           check_cpu!95!100
            check_period            24x7
            notification_options    w,c,r
}


define host{
    use                     linux
    host_name               geeko
    alias                   geeko
    address                 10.1.1.3
    notification_options    d,r
}
define service{
            use                     linux
            host_name               geeko
            active_checks_enabled   0
            check_freshness         0
            service_description     Host Alive
            check_command           check_alive
            check_period            24x7
}

define service{
            use                     linux
            host_name               geeko
            active_checks_enabled   0
            check_freshness         0
            service_description     CPU
            check_command           check_cpu!95!100
            check_period            24x7
            notification_options    w,c,r
}
```

Comment: Please explain the data you have shown. I can't tie it up with the description of your problem you have written. Please also show the attempts you have made that aren't working for you

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to do this on a periodic basis, it really sounds like you want to define a macro in your text editor and use a few clever search and replace tricks or, if you do need to do this over and over again, you might want to look into a template processing solution.

Comment: OR I would like to search two patters

Comment: So, again, my question is how often do you need to do it.  If you have to do it all the time, then automate it. If you only have to do it once a quarter, and it takes 10 minutes inside an editor, it's probably worth just getting a beverage, and doing it by hand.

Comment: Len, appreciate your suggestion I need to look at macro.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! >service.txt
> active_checks_enabled   0
> check_freshness         0
> service_description     Host Alive
> check_command           check-host-alive
> check_period            24x7
> }
> !
sed -i -e '/define host{/,/}/{/define host/h;/use/H;/host_name/H;/}/{G;s/host/service/;r service.txt' -e '}}' huge_text_file.txt
```